# Node js - Why lstatSync(Path) returns undefined ? - synchronously check

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, asynchronous

I'm new to Node.js , and i'm trying to create a simple server

the problem is:

> - TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFile' of undefined

what i did so far :

- I tried a simple debugging process to find out where the problem exactly
- and the problem as i expect in the returning value of `lstatSync()`
- `lstatSync()` returns undefined all the time , which is a cause the problem in `isFile()`

Notes :-

- I checked in a sample code below the path that i pass to `lstatSync()` by logging the value in the console and it was as expected
- Also after some research i tried to use `fs.exists()` but i found out that it's deprecated !
- Finally the [Docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v0.12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstatsync_path) doesn't provide much about the function

Sample Code :

```
var http = require("http"); // creating server
var path = require("path"); // finding the actual path for directories / files 
var url = require("url"); // parse url
var fs = require('fs'); // file system core , dealing with files operations


// Array of mime types ..
var mimeTypes = {
    'html' : 'text/html',
    'css'  : 'text/css',
    'js'   : 'text/javascript',
    'jpg'  : 'image/jpg',
    'png'  : 'image/png',
    'jpeg' : 'image/jpeg'
}

// creating server ...
http.createServer(function(req , res){

    var uri = url.parse(req.url).pathname // parse url , exctract the path after the host name 'incuding /'
    var fileName = path.join(process.cwd(),unescape(uri)); // returing current directory path , unescape the url path in case it contains special char. 
    console.log("data is loading"+uri);
    console.log("File name : "+fileName);
    var stats;

    try {
        stats = fs.lstatSync(fileName) // Returns an instance of fs.Stats.
        console.log(stats);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(stats);      
        // if the file not exists [NOT FOUND]
        res.writeHead(404,{'Context-Type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('Error 404 , page not Found \n');
        res.end();
    }

    // file actual path is a file / directory

    // file it's a file 
    if(stats.isFile()){
        var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(fileName).split('.').reverse()[0]]; // file name without extension
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':mimeType});
        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
        readStream.pipe(res);
    }else if(stats.isDirectory()){
        res.writeHead(302,{
            'Location' : 'index.html'
        });
        res.end();
    }else{
        res.writeHead(500,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('500 Internal Error \n');
        res.end();
    }

}).listen(8888);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `res.end()` doesn't magically stop the rest of the function to run. In the `catch` handler, you should return from the function explicitly:

```
try {
    stats = fs.lstatSync(fileName) // Returns an instance of fs.Stats.
    console.log(stats);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(stats);      
    // if the file not exists [NOT FOUND]
    res.writeHead(404,{'Context-Type':'text/plain'});
    res.write('Error 404 , page not Found \n');
    return res.end();
}
```

Note that the HTTP server doesn't do anything with the return value of the handler, so `return res.end()` is just a shortcut for `res.end(); return;`.

Comment: As a *separate* statement. `return res.end();` is misleading, suggesting that the return value of the callback has any meaning. It doesn't. `res.end(); return;` avoids confusing the issue.

Comment: Thanks Sir i got it ,but still that's doesn't solve the problem of the returning value of `lstatSync()` which is undefined all the time

Comment: @Ashraf add `console.log(e)` inside the `catch` to see which error is thrown. Most likely, the path (`fileName`) is incorrect.

Comment: @robertklep i did that sir and the result was even weird that's the path `c:\Users\amt\Desktop\Projects with Node js\index.htm` instead of `C:\Users\amt\Desktop\Projects with Node js\01.simple-web-server\index.htm` , why he can't include `01.simple-web-server` Folder in the path ? , what happened that he ignored `01.simple-web-server` folder  , why that happened ?

Comment: @Ashraf what exactly is the URL that's being requested?

Comment: `localhost:8888/index.html`

Comment: @Ashraf do you start the server from the `01.simple-web-server` folder, or from its parent folder? The code is trying to read a file that's relative to the folder in which the server is started (and not relative to the folder in which the server file is located).

Comment: @robertklep yeah i understand now , thanks sir for your time , i really appreciated :)